# Issue with JQuery Country and State cascading dropdown showing all states until country dropdown changed

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have cascading dropdowns for country and state in my laravel project. I am using JQuery to refresh the list of available states, depending on the country selected in the country dropdown. This works perfectly.

My issue is when I want to go back and change the state. If i go back to edit the state, because I haven't changed the country dropdown, the state dropdown just lists all states.

I have the states trigered on a change event with the country dropdown box. I am thinking, a quick and dirty method might be to also have the state dropdown refresh on a page load, but i am having issues implementing it.

This is what i have so far,

This is the JQuery in the view

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        jQuery('select[name="country"]').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = jQuery(this).val();
        if(countryID)
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '/getStates/' +countryID,
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    jQuery('select[name="state"]').empty();
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                    $('select[name="state"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('select[name="state"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

This is the view dropdown box code showing the country and state dropdowns.

```
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-11 col-md-5">
                        <label class="form-country" for="country">Country</label>
                        <select v-model="form.country" class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
                            @foreach ($countries as $country)
                                <option value="{{ $country->id }}" {{ $user->country_id == $country->id ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $country->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-11 col-md-3">
                        <label class="form-state" for="state">State</label>
                        <select v-model="form.state" class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                            @foreach ($states as $state)
                                <option value="{{ $state->id }}" {{ $user->state_id == $state->id ? "selected" : ""}}>{{ $state->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

As I said, it works fine, if I first change the country dropdown, the state dropdown will refresh, but if I want to change the state, without changing the country first, then I just get a list of all states. i think if i can trigger the state data refresh on a page load event might fix it, but i can't figure out how to do in JQuery.

Comment: Hi msg, sorry, I am not sure what you mean, can you elaborate further? I'm not great with JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing the `country` list should be as easy as calling `jQuery('select[name="country"]').trigger('change')` after setting up the listener, the only caveat is that you'll lose the current `state` selection, since you'll be emptying and repopulating it. You can get around that by saving its value first and check if it's present in the new state list.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // Cache the jQuery objects, don't look them up in each access
        var $countrySelector = jQuery('select[name="country"]');
        var $stateSelector = jQuery('select[name="state"]');
        
        $countrySelector.on('change',function(){
            var countryID = $countrySelector.val();
            var stateID = $stateSelector.val();
            
            if(countryID)
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : '/getStates/' +countryID,
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $stateSelector.empty();
                        jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                            // Check if current element matches previous selection
                            $stateSelector.append(
                                `<option value="${key}"${key == stateID ? ' selected' : ''}>${value}</option>`
                            );
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $stateSelector.empty();
            }
    });
    
    // After document is loaded and handler set up, fire the handler
    $countrySelector.trigger('change');
});
```

Further reference for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: That is awesome, thanks msg, that works perfectly. Thanks for showing me the cache, that is super helpful, glad you showed that to me.